# How to Save a File with a Filename Using a TimeCode in Linux

Tags: linux, macros, filenames

I'm on a tablet pc (Lenovo X60) so my keyboard is not available all (most) of the time, AND I'm trying out Linux Mint instead of Windows.

The main thing I'm missing is my AutoHotKey :(

I need to figure out how to give a filename a timecode of year-month-day-hour-minute-second so it would look like this: 20111117191833 (for readability's sake, 2011/11/17 19:18:33)

But in Linux I don't know how to do this?

And I'm aware of IronAHK but I haven't even gotten it to use the Send command correctly :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linux `date` command includes some very powerful formatting commands, it is worth checking out the man page to see what is possible on your system. It's also worth noting that you can capture the stdout of the date process using backticks.

For example, to create a new empty file with the current timestamp you could use:

```
touch `date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`
```